# Shiny and ColReorder, doesn't sort properly after column after drag and drop

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

Code to reproduce the issue:

(shiny version 1.6.0, DT version 0.18)

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  DTOutput("tbl"),
  br()
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output$tbl <- renderDT({
    datatable(mtcars, extensions = "ColReorder", 
              options = list(colReorder = TRUE)
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[initial state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXm8j.png)

1. Click in a column header (for example qsec). Check that the order is correct.
   [after sorting qsec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovmvL.png)
2. Drag the column to another position
   [after dragging qsec between drat and wt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOBH9.png)
3. Click in the column header of the dragged column. Check that the order is incorrect.
   [after sorting qsec in ascendent order, check that the values show that is not sorted 16.9, 18.52, 19.9, 18.9...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj6mL.png)

It seems to me that it looses the right indexing when dragging and dropping and it's sorting by another column. I have tried to run the datatable without Shiny and it works well.

Am I missing something?

UPDATE: I noticed that it works well with server=FALSE, but I need it to work properly with server=TRUE.

Also adding a link to deployed app so that you can see what I mean.
https://nmuenter.shinyapps.io/colreorder/

Comment: It appears to be working OK for me, can you add an example to your original post?

Comment: Hi @norie, I added more detail (screenshots) to the original post. Sorting is not working as expected after drag and drop

Comment: I see what you mean now, I originally thought the problem was with the order of the columns not the rows. However, I still can't reproduce the problem - however I drag the columns the order or the rows persist. Is there anything else going on in your actual app that's not in the posted code?

Comment: Nothing else, I reproduce the issue with the same exact code and have other colleagues that have the same issue :-S. No idea what I'm missing.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but at any point are you double clicking a column header?

Comment: haha, I'm not, and if I would, I would expect to have it sorted (but in the reverse order). And right now it is not. I think it is sorting by the column on the right (wt) that was previously in the qsec position